# Upload docker image to GCR through python

Tags: python, docker, google-container-registry

I'm working on a python code where I need to build a docker image and push it to GCR (Google Container Registry). I'm able to create a docker image using *Docker SDK for Python* however I'm not able to find out a way to push it to gcr. I was looking into `docker_client.images.push()`method but I don't see a way to connect to gcr using this method. I can build the docker image using `docker_client.images.build()` but not able to find any way to push it to google container registry. There are ways to push it to docker registry but I need specific to gcr.

I have already implemented this using google cli or through Azure DevOps however I'm trying to do the same using python application.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How would you do this using only command-line tools?  Does directly translating that to docker-py calls work?  (Usually the registry name is part of the image name.)

Comment: I have gcloud sdk installed on my local and on a vm as well which is dedicated for the pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have worked for me using the [Docker SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
import docker

client  = docker.from_env()

image, logs = client.images.build(path="<path/to/your/docker-repo>")

image_dest = "gcr.io/<your-gcp-project>/<your-repo-name>"

image.tag(image_dest)

client.api.push(image_dest)
```

I also had to add permissions with `gcloud auth configure-docker`.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at the container registry python library?
https://github.com/google/containerregistry

Or better yet, have you considered switching to go
https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry